# How to unsubscribe observer on server side

Tags: system.reactive, .net-remoting

I have an application which uses RX via remoting with one server (observable) and many clients (observers).
My problem is when a client(observer) disconnects not properly without performing ubsubscribe(dispose), the OnNext() function on the server is starting to throw remoting exception.

Is there any mechanism to unsubsribe the problematic observer on the server side?

The part of client code:

```
internal void SetRemoting(bool refreshInstance)
{
    string channelName = "RemotingClientUI";
    IDictionary dict = new Hashtable();
    dict["port"] = 9988;
    dict["name"] = channelName;

    var bcp = new BinaryClientFormatterSinkProvider();
    var channel = new TcpClientChannel(dict, bcp);
    ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(channel, false);

    _remoteServer = (IRemoteServerService) Activator.
        GetObject(typeof (IRemoteServerService),
            tcp://...");
}

private void SubscribeToRemoteEvents(bool unSubscrubeFirst)
{            
    _jobRowUpdate = _remoteServer.JobRowUpdate.Subscribe(UpdateJobQueueRow);
    _packageRowUpdate = _remoteServer.PackageRowUpdate.   
        Subscribe(UpdatePackageQueueRow);
    _miscUpdate = _remoteServer.MiscAction.Subscribe(MiscRemoteActions);
}
```

The part of server code:

```
public class RemoteServiceService
{
    public RemoteServiceService()
    {
        JobRowUpdate = LoggerFactory.GetLogger(
            LoggerType.RemoteService, this).JobRowUpdate.Remotable();
        PackageRowUpdate = LoggerFactory.GetLogger(
            LoggerType.RemoteService, this).PackageRowUpdate.Remotable();
        MiscAction = LoggerFactory.GetLogger(
            LoggerType.RemoteService, this).MiscActions.Remotable();
    }
}

public class RemoteLoggerForService
{
    private RemoteLoggerForService(IService service)
    {
        _jobRowUpdate = new Subject<IJobQueueRow>();
        _packageRowUpdate = new Subject<IPackageQueueRow>();
        _miscActions = new Subject<MiscRemoteObjects>();
        _service = service;
    }

    #region Overrides of LoggerBase

    public override void WriteToLog<T>(T stringFormatOrObject, 
        params object[] args)
    {
        lock (this)
        try
        {
            lock (LockLogger)
            {
                if (stringFormatOrObject is IJobQueueRow && 
                    _jobRowUpdate != null)
                {
                    _jobRowUpdate.OnNext(
                        stringFormatOrObject as IJobQueueRow);
                }

                if (stringFormatOrObject is IPackageQueueRow && 
                    _packageRowUpdate != null)
                {
                    _packageRowUpdate.OnNext(
                        stringFormatOrObject as IPackageQueueRow);
                }

                if (stringFormatOrObject is MiscRemoteObjects && 
                    _miscActions != null)
                {
                    _miscActions.OnNext(
                        stringFormatOrObject as MiscRemoteObjects);
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            LoggerFactory.GetLogger(LoggerType.File, null).
                WriteToLog(
                    Utils.GetFullException("RemoteLoggerForService", ex));
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Consider re-phrasing this. I don't understand your question. It seems like you might be conflating issues with Rx and remoting, when the problem lies with one or the other.

Comment: The observable and observers are on different computers. I'm using ISubject<T>.Remotable() extension. All is working fine, but disconnecting of the client causes to server crush with "remoting exception". The question is how to cause to Observable collection to ignore or to remove the subscription of client that already disconnected

Comment: How are you subscribing? Have you added the error/exception handler? or a Catch? You need to provide more information.

Comment: You may want to consider another approach ... such as PushQa which uses Rx + SignalR and OData and IQbservables for remote subscriptions.  http://petegoo.github.com/Pushqa/

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is swallow the exception and have your server carry on. You can do this by catching the exception (as you have done here) which you can then pass to the `OnError` method of the relevant Observable, so the subscribers can then choose how to react.